# How to Convert a string to date in batch scripting?

Tags: batch-file

I want to create task Scheduler  using batch script to run a .exe file to remove all setup after 40 days from installation. So I am calculating and getting  the date after current date in string format.

```
::After Executing some command line now my values are
::newDD=22
::newMM=7
::newYYYY=2017
echo "%newMM%/%newDD%/%newYYYY%"
set nxtDate=%newMM%/%newDD%/%newYYYY%
echo %nxtDate%

schtasks /create /tn "laptopAuditseldsestrt" /tr 
"D:\LatestTest\LaptopAudit\exe_files\uninstall.exe"  /sc once /st 23:59:00 /sd %nxtDate% /f
```

Now my problem is am getting 
ERROR: Invalid Start Date (Date should be in "mm/dd/yyyy" format). while creating task scheduler. Please help how to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
::newYYYY=2017
set /a newmm+=100
set /a newdd+=100
echo "%newMM:~-2%/%newDD:~-2%/%newYYYY%"
```

It would appear that the required format is 2 digits for day and month, so by adding 100 to the values calculated in `newxx`, then using only the last 2 characters of the value, the leading zeroes are generated.

Comment: Thank You Sir, My problem Solved.